# Zapier is creating list with records I can't use

Tags: api, zapier

Using a customized request in Zapier webhooks, I get a list of records but it is not parsing information in a way I can use it.

I'm using `Content-Type = application/xml`

Here's a sample of the output during the test:

[image: Zapier snapshot]

And here's how it shows the values when I try to use them:
[image: screenshot]

I've tried different apps and options in Zapier but I can't do anything with the output I get.

Here's the background if you're wondering...
I'm trying to get customer records from a third-party application that is the cloud. The endpoint in this app doesn't allow to update customer records by first and last name, only by customer ID. So, when the customer is new, works perfectly, but the record already exists we only get a worthless response from the app stating that the customer can't be created because it already exists (duh!), and it doesn't include any information about the record. Therefore, since the App doesn't allow getting customer records using filters, we need to get a complete list with ALL customer records in a separate step and then try to find the ID of the customer by using first and last name, so we can obtain the customer ID which is required to create a WordOrder in separated step.

I would appreciate any thoughts around this.

Answer (score 1):

`Webhook By Zapier` auto parse response and it is not posible to handle the scenario that you are trying to achieve using  `Webhook By Zapier`

I recommend using `fetch` API call in `Code By Zapier` .

You can found more info about the code by zapier at https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/javascript-code-examples-in-zaps